# Getting played youtube videos in firefox 7.x

Tags: firefox, download, youtube

I am trying to get a played youtube video from Firefox cache.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and Firfox 7.0.1

**Note, Firefox is still open and the video is complete loading**

I've tried go to `~/.mozilla/firefox/9qhsyom8.default/Cache` but the directory structure seems changed a lot:

```
hewedy@compu10:~/.mozilla/firefox/9qhsyom8.default/Cache$ ls -l
total 32072
drwx------ 24 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 09:30 0
drwx------ 32 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:56 1
drwx------ 23 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:57 2
drwx------ 26 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 05:20 3
drwx------ 19 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:57 4
drwx------ 28 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 03:37 5
drwx------ 29 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:43 6
drwx------ 29 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 09:58 7
drwx------ 19 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:56 8
drwx------ 24 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:24 9
drwx------ 25 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 07:46 A
drwx------ 25 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 04:15 B
drwx------ 20 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:42 C
-rw-------  1 mhewedy mhewedy  2093091 2012-02-24 10:58 _CACHE_001_
-rw-------  1 mhewedy mhewedy  5627862 2012-02-24 10:58 _CACHE_002_
-rw-------  1 mhewedy mhewedy 25042643 2012-02-24 10:58 _CACHE_003_
-rw-------  1 mhewedy mhewedy      276 2012-02-23 23:41 _CACHE_MAP_
drwx------ 22 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:44 D
drwx------ 25 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 09:57 E
drwx------ 19 mhewedy mhewedy     4096 2012-02-24 10:44 F
```

I then tried to copy all files in subdirectories into another directory:

```
mkdir ~/tmp/dir2 ; cp `find ./ -name "*"` ~/tmp/dir2
```

After I looked in `~/tmp/dir2` I found very few youtube files but cannot find the file I need.

I've also looked at : `/tmp/mozilla-media-cache/` but find no files!

**Please don't suggest a youtube download manager**

Answer (score 0):

(I'm using Gentoo, with firefox-10.0.1. Things might be significantly different in your version, I'm not familiar enough with firefox to tell.)

After loading up a video in youtube, I did this:

```
eroen@falcon ~ $ du .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/ | sort -n
[...]
512 .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/B
532 .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/2
1160    .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/8
14668   .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/7/40
14912   .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/7
23040   .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/
eroen@falcon ~ $ ls -lSr .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/7/40
total 14664
-rw------- 1 eroen users 15014104 Feb 24 11:50 55A2Fd01
eroen@falcon ~ $ mplayer .mozilla/firefox/sqaml9dr.default/Cache/7/40/55A2Fd01
```

I was then rewarded with a video in a small window of a double rainbow all the way across the sky.

Obviously, the names will be different for you, and unless your cache is clean before you start you will have a bit of trouble finding the correct files. You could clear your cache with something like this:

```
$ rm -r .mozilla/firefox/????????.default/Cache; \
mkdir .mozilla/firefox/????????.default/Cache
```

To clarify, I found the cache folder that took up the most space, looked inside it and played the only file there.